# SMTP Error Not able to login in moodle accounts

Tags: php, moodle

I download a theme in my moodle after that i tried to login into my moodle account it is not working it showing invalid username and password and if i try use forgot password after searching by username and emailid this message is coming.

"Error sending password change confirmation email"
and this link is showing
https://docs.moodle.org/35/en/error/moodle/cannotmailconfirm

so how can i change the SMTP Setting. With the help of code

Comment: but i using this on localhost so where should i inform about this?

Comment: You've downloaded a theme (which should be a grapical setting for your Moodle?), and now sending mails does no longer work? That sounds pretty weird

Comment: Well this error occur due to logintokens because of that if you login then it will show invalid credentials and when you try to forget username and  password then it will show you this error. If sounds weird but it will feel weird also when you try it.

Comment: There is nothing anybody else could try, as you haven't shared a single line of code or any other attempts to reproduce the problem

Comment: Well i only got this error when i was doing this and about code i didn't do any change before in moodle framework code so i had no idea about that also so i share what i have at the time. And i think that login tokens is set or built like that i didn't change that so i didn't produce this problem i just simply install the theme then this problem occur.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This problem is occurring because of your theme either you can remove the theme or if you don't want to remove the theme then go to this file path "moodle/lib/templates/loginform.mustache" and change the logintokens and refer moodle docs for logintokens this will help.